# Output laravel php escaped html code into a hidden input field

Tags: php, html

So, I have a form which has a hidden input, I want to output some html code into from my database, but I don't want the html to render, I just want it to be the value of the input.. like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="content" val="{!! $page->content !!}" required>
```

Template content is a full html page with many tags, so it ends up breaking everything.. How can I escape it so it will be only as a value?

I am using laravel php

Comment: its `value` not `val`

Answer (score 0):

use this.
`<input type="hidden" name="content" val="{!! htmlspecialchars($page->content) !!}" required>`